# Как на Си отследить нажатие расширенных кодов клавиш? (стрелки)

Tags: c, клавиатура

Есть способ в консоле, отследить курсорные клавиши? Там получается при getch() получаем первый код 224, а вторым считыванием 75 для стрелки в лево. Но ASCII 224 совпадает с буквой "р" . И если в логике читать следующий символ то букву "р" нет возможности ввести с первого раза. Я написал функцию ввода, редактирования, строки. Но перемещение право лево не получается. Хотя какая-то стандартная функция это делает. Но ей не как не передать строку для редактирования. Я читал, есть вариант с getchar() с отключением ECHO вывода буфера. Но может это как-то проще делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не попробуете?

```
for(;;)
{
    int k = getch();
    cout << hex << k;
    if (kbhit())
    {
        int m = getch();
        cout << "  " << hex << m;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Ну т.е. если что-то есть нажатое сразу же, то...

Comment: Работает! Благодарю. Есть же вариант без "мазохизма" и под Windows ;)

int main()
{
    for(;;)
{
    int k = getch();
    //cout << hex << k;
    printf("%X\n",k);
    if (kbhit())
    {
        int m = getch();
        //cout << "  " << hex << m;
        printf("  %X\n",m);
    }
    //cout << endl;
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}

Т.е. по логике kbhit проверяет есть ли еще код в буфере клавы?

Comment: Да, есть ли необработанное нажатие (код в буфере).

Answer (score 0):

Перевод ответа [getch and arrow codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432632/21345860):

При нажатии одной из клавиш стрелок, `getch` помещает в буфер 3 значения:

- `\033`
- `[`
- `A`, `B`, `C` или `D`

Поэтому код должен выглядеть как то так:

```c
if (getch() == '\033') { // если первое значение esc последовательность 
    getch(); // пропустить [
    switch(getch()) { // реальное значение 
        case 'A':
            // Код стрелки вверх 
            break;
        case 'B':
            // Код стрелки вниз
            break;
        case 'C':
            // Код стрелки вправо
            break;
        case 'D':
            // Код стрелки влево
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я видел этот пример и он не работает! Может он работает в Линуксе, там по другому (по ходу) коды обрабатываются. А в Винде приходит рК рМ рН рР (р русская, код 224). Это типа в винде (224) код расширенной клавиши. У меня в логике считывания ch=getch(); по справочнику ch это int.

Comment: Я твой пример вставил в CodeBlocks и в CASE блоке перед break; поставил printf("направление");
И оно не заходит в блок свич! Ибо '\033' не из вселенной винды по ходу ;)
Я ведь не зря такой вопрос задал ;) Если бы все так просто было :))))

Comment: Да они там в комментах про Unix getch() пишут.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75499310/21345860

Comment: Тоже классный пример ;) но при нажатии "р" русской, она пропадает в логике и только при повторном нажатии на "р"(русскую) она появляется в строке ввода ;)
Вся и проблема не работы этого кода, в совпадении 224 с малой буквой р (русской) :)

Comment: Вся и проблема не работы этого кода, в совпадении 224 с малой буквой р (русской) :)
И я в поисках этой проблемы, находил пример с отключением ECHO в функции getchar(). Она при нажатии делает 2 вещи, в переменную посылает код и выводит на экран. Но я потерял где я находил пример тот. Подумав вначале что это бред :)))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866394/how-to-read-char-without-echo

Типа вот такой схемы. Но она мне не понятна вообще :(
Т.е. типа в момент ввода или редактирования строки, я выключаю ECHO а потом включаю, по окончании ввода или редактирования.

Comment: Результат `getch`, в какой тип записываешь?

Comment: Я писал, по инструкции в int

Comment: Попробуй библиотеку ncurces

Comment: Спасибо. Почитал, там много полезных функций. Больше конечно для Юникс используют, там терминалы "рулят" ;)
Ниже Harry прислал рабочий вариант. Теперь моя функция сможет вводить и изменять существующий текст в строке, используя курсорные кнопки. И т.к. в момент ввода текста нельзя было выйти в меню к примеру, теперь можно, нажав расширенную клаву :)
Да и расширив её функционал, можно целый текстовый редактор в консоли дописать.
А все началось с увиденного примера GotoXY перемещения указателя в окне консоли ;)